# If find string in a cell, delete all data below it, else if string is not found do nothing

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post but I've used this site as a resource for VBA.
I want to simply search for the string "_____" that is in column A somewhere.
Once it's found I want to delete all data below it

If the string is not in Column A then do nothing.

The following code is close but not really what I'm looking for. This code will find all "___" in the worksheet and delete that row. Please help, I'm very new to this.

```vb
Sub test()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Do
        Set rng = Cells.Find(what:="_____")
        
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        
        Else
            MsgBox ("All headers deleted")
        
        End If
    
    Loop While (Not rng Is Nothing)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No looping required:

```vb
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="_____", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<~ or xlPart maybe

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A" & rng.Row + 1 & ":A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MATCH:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mtch As Long
    mtch = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
        mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("_____", ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), 0) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If mtch > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & mtch, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works like a charm, exactly what I was looking for.